# Jquery adds up only to two

Tags: jquery

Am trying to get my program to add 1 to the counter each time a button is clicked and id exists; 
But my problem is that when you click the third time it only alert 2 instead of 3 and I want it to go up to whenever possible
Is there any better way of achieving this, Thanks

here is my code:

```
Var q=1;
if ($("#"+val).length==0){
alert (q)
}else
{
q=q+1
alert (q)
}
```

please here is the full code of my button click, note that the var q is declared in global mode: i'm not an expert in this program please can someone modify my code so that i can get it to work

```
$(document).on('click',".add", function(){

var add=($(this).attr('id')) //this collect the id

var q=1;
        var val=($(this).attr("name"))

 if ($("#"+val).length==0) {

        alert(q)
 }else{
q=q+1
 alert(q)
 }
```

Comment: show your html and/or your whole implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare you `Var q=1;` as globally.

**Example**

```
Var q=1;
$('SELECTOR').click(function(){ /* increment code */ });
```

if its just typo then ignore or please put `;` to end the statement.

Comment: i tried your example but i'm still getting 1 instead of 2 or 3 here is my code:                                                                      }else{ $('SELECTOR').click(function(){ q=q+1; });
     alert(q);}

Comment: @david put `var q = 1; `outside of `document . on`

Comment: thanks it worked perfect, thanks to all the answers, i belive they're all correc

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable q as global variable so that it will be available through out the page life cycle , until you refresh the page .

```
     <script>
     var q = 1;
     function Myfunction()
     {
     // put your logic here and use the q 
     }  
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `q` as 0 to start with. Than you can skip the `if - else` ...

```
var q = 0;
$(document).off('click', 'SELECTOR').on('click', 'SELECTOR', function() {
    q++;
    alert(q);
)};
```

Edit:

Oké at first, your `var q` isn't as global as you think. It should be outside your click handler. As you wrote it, q will be set to 1 every time you click `.add`.

My code above replaces all of your code. But I'll adapt it to fit your needs even more...
(We were all starters once)

```
var q = 0;
$(document).off('click', '.add').on('click', '.add', function() {
    var add = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).attr("name");
    if($('#'+val).length != 0) {
        q++;
        alert(q);
    } 
    else {
        alert(q);
    }
)};
```

Note: I first use `.off()` just in case. I like it this way, if you don't you can leave only the `.on()` ...

Hope this helped you.

Comment: please can you review my latest post and tell me where to paste your suggested code, thanks

Comment: @DavidBukera I updated my answer for you.